# C# project cannot load referenced dll

Tags: c#

I have a C# solution which has 2 projects P1 and P2. 
These two projects are referencing same set of dynamic link libraries for their debug version but on Project P2, the debug version always get cannot load library error. Screenshot attached. Can someone please help and advise what I should do in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Screenshot is missing ...

Comment: First things to check - Are both P1 and P2 using the same .NET version? Are the referenced DLLs set to 'copy local' if required?